# tolower() not working

Tags: c, tolower

The below code snippet is used to convert a string to lower case.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char s[] = "AbS.d_";

    tolower(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the [output](http://ideone.com/ezOMA) as:

```
AbS.d_
```

Why the string is not being converted?

Comment: Because [tolower()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/tolower/) works character-by-character, and returns an *output*.  It doesn't convert the whole string at once.  And even if it did, it would cause an access violation on your static string ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 The string is not static (maybe the question was edited?)

Comment: @MatteoItalia, Indeed [it does](http://ideone.com/htlXf). The function takes an `int`, and you pass a pointer.

Comment: @chris I see your link and raise you [this one](http://liveworkspace.org/code/21386e9cba33a6b3fe603a3b2d016393).

Comment: @chris: you are right, I tend to forget how forgiving is C in respect to C++.

Comment: @LucDanton, I agree. Warnings would have maybe saved the OP's question.

Comment: @paulsm4: The documentation you cite doesn’t mention a critical point: when you pass a `char` argument, it must be cast to `unsigned char`, not to `int`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tolower.html for a better source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tolower` takes int and return lowered int.

This should work:

```
int i=0;
for(i=0; s[i]; i++)
{
    s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hello infinite loop. Don't you mean `for(i=0; s[i]; i++) { ... }`?

Comment: Technically it takes an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

`tolower` takes a character type as parameter, but you use a string. You need to run through your array, and call `tolower` for each character.

Comment: I think the implementation of `tolower` is guaranteed to be wait-free.