# why doesn't tolower convert my uppercase chars to lowercase?

Tags: c++, debugging, function, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tolower() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145463/tolower-not-working)

Here is my code:

```
char *ptr=&twod[j][i];

                 while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        tolower(*ptr);


        cout<<endl
            <<endl
            <<endl
            <<*ptr;

        ptr++;

    }
```

When I cout the above, the the uppercase letters still remain as uppercase. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: `tolower` is a function from the C standard library. Remember that in C, `someFunction(variable)` can *never* modify the variable, because C has no notion of references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
*ptr = tolower(*ptr);
```

[`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) *returns* the lowercase. It does **not** accept the argument *by reference*, hence it *cannot* modify `*ptr` which you pass to it.

Read [the documentation of `std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) for detail.

Comment: The argument to `tolower` must be cast to `unsigned char`. Read the documentation for detail.

Comment: @RolandIllig: The caller doesn't need to cast. Just pass `*ptr` which is `char` which is fine if it is not negative.

Comment: "If it’s not negative." — But who guarantees you that? There are popular implementations out there where `char` can be negative. Since the question doesn’t give examples of particular strings, you have to expect _any_ character.

Answer (score 2):

`tolower` doesn't modify the value, it returns a new one.

Try this:

```
*ptr = tolower(*ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`tolower` doesn't mutate its argument. Set a variable or print out the operation:

```
*ptr = tolower(*ptr);
std::cout << *ptr;
// or
std::cout << tolower(*ptr);
```